# VS Code crashing on restart after opening large file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I recently used VS code to open a large file by opening from the command line using the command line flag `--max-memory=12288mb`. I was able to edit the file fine and finished what I needed to do and then closed code as normal.

By default I have the `restoreWindows` and `hotExit` settings enabled, so that when I re-open code all the previous files are enabled.

After this whenever I open a VS Code via the shortcut or context menu, it attempts to re-open the large file and crashes within ~10 seconds of starting. And displays the warning:

> The Window Has Crashed
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience! You can reopen the window to continue where you left off

[image]

I tried a few steps to attempt to close/prevent the file reopening all during the functioning 10 seconds:

1. Close the tab using the 'x' icon
2. Using the `Close Editor`, `Close Folder` and `Close Window` options in the file menu
3. Setting `"window.restoreWindows": "none"` and `"files.hotExit": "off"` to try and prevent the file from automatically being reloaded

I have also tried running VS Code with extensions disabled

Comment: `vim` can edit large files with small memory footprint

Comment: @rioV8 I appreciate the suggestion, but that's not really the issue. Code handles the large file fine, it's the hot save/reload features that were preventing me from using it

Comment: Where do you set "window.restoreWindows": "none" and "files.hotExit": "off"?

Comment: @copcor in the VSCode settings file (link to explain how to access this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). That's was part of my steps that didn't work however. The answer below solved it for me. Vonc has also said there's been a fix for some recent builds, but I've not had a chance to try this out my self yet

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution was to start VS Code from the command line again with the following command

```
code --disable-extensions --max-memory=12288mb
```

Then to close the offending file and correctly exit VS Code without any open files. This then prevent VS Code from attempting to re-open the large file when restarting.

I believe that this is a bug in VS Code as it feels as though it should display the same warning to restart with the correct memory when re-loading files as it does when first attempting to open the file. I've raised a bug with MS [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80701).

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: I also had to do step 3 in the question do make VS code stop crashing continously

Comment: Maybe you can add this suggestion to GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode and provide some details.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete I've already raised this as a bug on their GitHub page, it's been looked into a bit but hasn't had much activity since it was raised. Link is in the answer or you can find it here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80701

Comment: `--max-memory` is being removed from vscode. please check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167719

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem on a relatively low-powered mac.  I had mistakenly attempted to open a 2+ GB txt file with vs code.  VS Code hung, and I ended up forcing it closed.  To my surprise, when I tried to reopen vs code, it then immediately tried to reopen that last file. No bueno.  Again, it would hang and cause the laptop I was on to grind to a near halt.  I searched high and low for a solution with no success until I saw @Fuempel's response above - he was on a windows machine, but it got me thinking about what the equivalent backup structure was on mac, and behold...

Please pardon my clumsy use of finder instead of the shell, as I am a novice mac/linux user ;-)

On Mac:

1. Open Finder  navigate to `~/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups` Note - You may need to get Finder to show
   hidden files and folders to view the path and its contents - a
   shortcut for this is to press **CMD+SHFT+.** to toggle this on/off.
2. You should have a file called `workspaces.json` in the directory, and at least one folder with an apparently random integer name. In my case, I had a directory named "1660046792691", and my workspaces.json contained the following:

```json
    {"rootURIWorkspaces":[],"folderWorkspaceInfos":[],"emptyWorkspaceInfos":[{"backupFolder":"1660046792691"}]}
```

**Note** that this "backupFolder" value points back to the folder in the same dir.

3. I deleted both the workspaces.json file, and the folder it referenced ("1660046792691").
4. I was then able to restart vs code without issue. VS Code will recreate the workspaces.json file and another workspace backup folder on restart.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to delete any folder under

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\**Backups**
```

Answer (score 1):

worked for me .. I had 2gig file open .. kept crashing over and over again

```
rd /q/s "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\"
```

Comment: This did work for me, but it also removes all your json preferences. Fortunately I had github sync so I was able to resync them back though.

Answer (score 1):

work for me (on fedora) :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedData/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible upcoming solution to prevent accidentally trying to open a large file is coming in vscode v1.75 (it is in the Insiders Build now).  There is a setting you can enable to force a confirmation dialog to pop up before the file is actually attempted to open.

[image: large file confirmation dialog]

See also [Add a confirmation to open large files behind a setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170090):

[image: GH issue: testing large file confirmation dialog]

Answer (score -1):

VSCode 1.64 (Dec. 2021) will likely *not* crash when attempting to reopen a large file.

That issue is followed by [issue 132771](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132771#issuecomment-990924096) and [issue 138805](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138805) ("Opening large binary files reads full contents")

The insider edition will include [commit e9eec21](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e9eec21dc1f908d60162b86c6439a0c2600ec0c4) by [Benjamin Pasero](https://github.com/bpasero):

> ### files - cancel reading when binary is encountered
>
> Make sure to cancel reading on error to stop file service activity as soon as possible.
> When for example a large binary file is read we want to cancel the read instantly.