# My VS code keeps crashing when opening it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the problem did not dissappear. It seems that when I open the app, more than 20 windows open  at the same time, causing the app to crash. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Desktop screenshot]

I've searched on the internet for what else to do, but I didn't come across any solution.

Comment: Have you seen [VS Code crashing on restart after opening large file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57887568/1115360)? Some of the suggestions there look like they could be relevant.

Comment: I've just checked the link you gave me and I found the solution. I had to open the app by running: code --disable-extensions --max-memory=12288mb  , in the cmd. And then I had to close all tabs manually, Everything seems to work fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The solution was to start VS Code from the command prompt with the following command:

```
code --disable-extensions --max-memory=12288mb
```

Then to close all open tabs and correctly exit VS Code without any open files.
Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Although i didn't have any tabs opened that could have been the culprit, in my case, i could not still figure out what was causing it to crash. But then, i did the above step + opened another instance to open a folder instead of default. Not sure what helped but I did try the above and then restored the extensions and so far, they are working.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the fixes above when my Ubuntu install of VS Code crashed repeatedly at startup. The only thing that worked for me was deleting the entire ~/.config/Code/Backups folder. Back it up first, just in case!

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue and Andrew's suggestion didn't work for me, but the --disable-chromium-sandbox flag did:

```
code --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-chromium-sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the latest version of VSCODE. Then i tried installing "Downloads: Windows: User" one from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52. It worked. I am not sure of the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that after installing the extension 'Django Template Support' the VSCode started crashing.
I tried by installing the latest version of VSCode too. Still the VSCode did crash.

Once after uninstalling that extension, VSCode is working fine.

May be, we should note the change which has made the VScode to crash (though, it shouldn't, I believe.)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023-Oct:
I have the latest version of VS Code (System wide version and not user type version).

My VS code used to keep crashing whenever i open with a dialog prompting me to choose one among the 3 (Retry | Cancel | Keep Waiting). Mostly, first 2 attempts will crash eventually even if i click Retry/Keey Waiting. That tells me like some plugin/extension was taking time to load and until that settles down, neither action on the dialog helps me to retain but from 3rd attempt, it allowed me a sec or 2 at least to respond click on "Keep waiting". That will at least dont let the VS Code to crash itself but will stay on load.

I had the below extensions that i eventually removed and that kinda sorted out for me.

- Oracle VS Code tools
- sqltools
- Azure Connect
- Azure Devops pipelines
- github pull requests and issues
- Microsoft Edge tools for VS code (disabled)
- Angular snippets
- Python snippets (not published from MS)

I am not saying these extensions are culprits, but my VS Code is on my work device and that goes through network/security scans and things, i felt may slow down and these are not needed for me now. Some that may try to utilize resources in syncing/network folder paths are also a factor.

I also had some tabs from OneDrive although they are having a local version, but the path is part of the OneDrive sync folder. I had to close them too.

After these are done, it's better and not crashing at all for me. Tried testing it by opening and closing it multiple times although they are slow to show up for full use.

In summary:

- any files that are opened and kept open tab from network drive/path, like OneDrive or other shared folder path --> dont keep it as open tab.
- any extensions that are no longer required (remove them)
- any extensions that has alternate tools to manage like Oracle, sqltools etc can be removed
- any extensions that may require more scanning, scrutiny from work/corporate security, better be disabled/lazy load/ondemand load/enabled. (this may vary by each person's use case, for me, i assume, github pull requests and issues, third party extensions like sqltools, network touching extensions)