# VSCode crashes on startup (code: -1073741818)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yesterday, VSCode (1.67.1) decided that it was unable to start (crashes immediately) and spits out the error code -1073741818. I have the option to reopen or close but nothing happens regardless of the option chosen. Thought it might be an issue with the file/folder I was opening but no success opening any files/folders at all. Tried to disable GPU, disable extensions and re-install but all lead to the same error code. Tried to move to Atom, but, oddly enough, the same issue occurred. Discovered Atom and VSCode are both based on Electron and that Electron has previously had issues with Nvidia drivers (currently running 512.77) so I tried to install previous versions of the drivers that were working but no success. I finally gave up and moved the code to another system and everything works flawlessly.

So now I that I have some time, I am trying to figure out what went wrong and where to go from here. My uninformed, uneducated guess is it is driver related but I am not sure how to resolve it. I was able to successfully use VSCode earlier in the day with no issue. The system went into stand-by mode and upon return, the issue began. Any suggestions/guidance on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

[VSCode Crash Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAp3k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! I think this is caused by an corrupt installation of vscode, try to restart your computer and maybe reinstall vscode by going to, https://code.visualstudio.com.

If that does not help maybe try to submit an issue on the vscode github here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode.

**How to submit an issue on github**:

1. Find the menu bar where it has multiple menus, it should have: "code", "pull requests" and "issues".
2. Click on "issues" button.
3. Click "new issue" to create an issue.
4. Then click "bug report" and enter details to file issue.
5. Once ready click submit issue to submit your issue in github.

Also, you'll need a github account to create a issue, signup here: https://github.com/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I attempted to uninstall vscode, restart, download a fresh copy of the installation file from the link you provided but no luck. It is strange that it is affecting two different programs in a similar manner. I am not sure it is limited to VSCode at this point since both programs seems to be responding the same way. Is it possible some dependency is corrupted? In the meantime, I'll create an issue on github like suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you've installed any additional extensions which may be causing the VSCode to crash.

[My VS code keeps crashing when opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070794/my-vs-code-keeps-crashing-when-opening-it/73635462#73635462)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First, it used to crash once every 10 minutes, then it started crashing 10 times a minute after a few hours. It just stopped working that day.

I don't know how it was resolved but it did automatically resolve.

I searched for the solution but the VS code on GitHub was already closed. If applicable take a rest and let your PC calm down also. Then if the problem doesn't get resolved, try contacting the developer team.