# How can I fix VSCode crashing when opened as half a window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work with VSCode in [half a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im1wm.jpg) to do other things on the other half.

I get the following error message when I try and run a cpp file in this way: [cpp error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLAMq.png)

A similar error message when I try and run a python file: [python error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRy4P.png)

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887568/vs-code-crashing-on-restart-after-opening-large-file), with `code --disable-extensions --max-memory=12288mb` but it still persists.

The errors don't show up when vscode is in full screen mode.

Raw error text:

```
Last 200 Keys:
 - - s t d o u t = M i c r o s o f t - M I E n g i n e - O u t - c b g l g b d j . l 0 l ' Space ' - - s t d e r r = M i c r o s o f t - M I E n g i n e - E r r o r - 3 u m y i n v f . m w i ' Space ' - - p i d = M i c r o s o f t - M I E n g i n e - P i d - 0 b r z o z y 0 . q 0 f ' Space ' - - d b g E x e = C : \ m s y s 6 4 \ m i n g w 6 4 \ b i n \ g d b . e x e ' Space ' - - i n t e r p r e t e r = m i ' Space Enter


Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.
Parameter name: left
Actual value was -1.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Internal.VirtualTerminal.set_CursorLeft(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReallyRender(RenderData renderData, String defaultColor)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ForceRender()  
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Insert(Char c) 
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.SelfInsert(Nullable`1 key, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ProcessOneKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key, Dictionary`2 dispatchTable, Boolean ignoreIfNoAction, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.InputLoop()    
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
```

```
Last 6 Keys:
 & Space C : / U

Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.
Parameter name: left
Actual value was -1.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Internal.VirtualTerminal.set_CursorLeft(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReallyRender(RenderData renderData, String defaultColor)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ForceRender()  
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Insert(Char c) 
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.SelfInsert(Nullable`1 key, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ProcessOneKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key, Dictionary`2 dispatchTable, Boolean ignoreIfNoAction, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.InputLoop()    
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
```